# How to get a z alpha over 2 in python

Tags: python, statistics

I'm working on finding the minimum number of replication to meet a certain confidence interval (e.g. 10%). I wonder whether there is a function in Python could directly get the z value with a input alpha.

A similar function is `stats.t.ppf(1-0.05, 999)` for the t-statistic.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `stats.norm`:

```
In [1]: from scipy import stats

In [2]: stats.norm.ppf(1-0.05)
Out[2]: 1.6448536269514722
```

It has the same API as `stats.t`.